# Drawing Level Curves of a Minimum Function

Tags: analysis, multivariable-calculus

I have a question relating to the drawing of level curves:

I have been given the function $f(x,y) = \min\{x+2,y\}$ and am now trying to figure out a way to draw the level curve. Under functions of a different type, I usually set a level z and solve for y but in this case, I do not know how to do it.

I would really appreciate your help.

Kind regards, 
JAspen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solve it the same way, $$\{z\mid z = \min\{x+2, y\}\} = \{z\mid z = x+2\wedge x+2\le y\}\cup\{z\mid z = y\wedge y\le x+2\}.$$ Thus, a curve of level $z$ for $f$ consists of chunks of curves of level $z$ for $f_1(x, y) = x+2$ and $f_2(x, y) = y$ for whichever $f_i$ is less. So you solve $x+2 \le y$ and see in which region to take a chunk of whose level curve.

[image: Level curves of $\min\{f_1, f_2\}$ are highlighted.]

Comment: First of all, thank you very much for your answer. However, I do not know how to visualize your answer in a graph: Do I start at x=y=0 and continue in steps of 1, and put it on a two-dimensional graph? And how does z influence the graph. Say, z = 2, how does this influence the minimum function? Does one of y or x+2 have to equal z?

Comment: @JAspen I’ve added a picture.